# Python-Does For loop have a return value?(I know this is lame,but take a look)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
int(x) for x in range(3)
```

I know this for loop is absurd,but bear with me.Here in this block of code what i think is happening is (Correct me if i am wrong)-X is assigned with the 0 value at first and will return,Okay this is fine.

```
[1 for x in range(3) if a[x] > b[x]]
```

In this case what is happening is if the statement is correct it is returning 1 and if it isn't it is returning nothing.
Am i getting this right, Is saying for loops have return values right?
ThankYou.

Comment: Loops are not functions. They don't have return values. It is possible that you are confusing comprehensions and loops.

Comment: `int()` and `range()` are functions that `return` values, your list comprehension (or a `for` loop) is just a way of iterating over these

Comment: Yes,I got the answer i must be looking for list comprehension in google.Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have posted seems like part of a list comprehension (you probably removed the outer []-braces).

Have a look here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

A good way to see the execution of a Python script is to use [this tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit). But you need to indicate what `a` and `b` are (lists ? strings ?).

```
a = [4,5,6,8]
b = [1,2,3,4]

print([1 for x in range(3) if a[x] > b[x]])
```

Output :

```
[1,1,1]
```

This is equivalent to :

```
tmp = []
for x in range(3):
    if a[x] > b[x]:
        tmp.append(1)
print(tmp)
```